# How to zoom in gallery?

Tags: android

I have gallery with custom web views. My adapter:

```
public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
    int GalItemBg;
    private Context cont;

    public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
        cont = c;
        TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
        GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        typArray.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return pagesArray.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return pagesArray[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final WebView wView = pagesArray[position];
        if(wView!=null){
            if(wView.loaded==0){
                wView.setInitialScale(50);
                wView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                wView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
                wView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
                wView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                wView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

                wView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
                        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                        wView.loaded = 1;
                    }

                });

                wView.loadUrl(URL_TO_LOAD);
                wView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);
                Gallery.LayoutParams params = new Gallery.LayoutParams(400, 430);
                wView.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        }
        return wView;

    }

}
```

And, how to implement zoom in gallery in such a way that all the whole will increase/decrease?

Comment: I post a link of sample code at [here][1], hopes it can help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268806/android-gallery-with-pinch-zoom

Answer (score 1):

There are no functions that allow you to do this with imageview or gallery.

But here is a excellent tutorial to get you on your way.

[Pinch zoom](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with viewflipper, why dont you try like this.I have paste my code here .
 http://www.anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/horizontal-grid-view-in-android-t56753.html